# How to do a HTTP Get request with a deferred inside another (cascade defer)?

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

I am want to do a GET request to check if the return code is what I expect. This request occurrs inside a function called by a addCallback of a general deferred chain, as is showed in the bellow code.

My specif question if: **How to make the return of line -D- arrives at line -E-?**

It seems that the callback function "cbResponse" (line -D-) never is called. My first attempt was do the request and return to the callback chain the result of the request (line -A-). It fails, because the deferr object hasn't the attribute result.
The second attemp (line -B-), was return the deferred object itself. It doesn't returns the result too.
The third attemp (line -C-), whas return anything, but it obviously hasn't the response code of the request.

Thanks a lot!

```
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer

class Test (object):


    @classmethod
    def getRequest (self, result):

        print "Function getRequest"

        agent = Agent(reactor)

        d2 = agent.request('GET',
                           'http://www.google.com',
                           Headers({'User-Agent': ['Twisted Web Client Example']}),
                           None)

        d2.addCallback(Test.cbResponse)

        # 1 st attempt: return the result of d2. Fail: exceptions.AttributeError: Deferred instance has no attribute 'result'
        return d2.result            # --> line A

        # 2nd attempt: return only the deferr object d2. Don't fail, but I can't get the result of the above request
        ### return d2                   # --> line B

        # 3rd attemp: return None (without return). 
                                    # --> line C   

    @classmethod
    def cbResponse(response):

        print 'Function cbResponse %s', response.code
        # This is the return value I want to pass back to deferredChain function (called at line E)
        return response.code            # line --> D

    @classmethod
    def deferredChain(self):
        d = defer.Deferred()

        d.addCallback(Test.getRequest)  # line --> E
        d.callback("success")

        return d.result                 # line --> F



if __name__ == '__main__':
    tst = Test()
    rtn = tst.deferredChain()
    print "RTN: %s " % rtn
```

Comment: Please rephrase the question because it is not clear what is the problem and what is the question.

Comment: Sorry @pinturic, I did a adjust. Please see if is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You're using [Twisted Agent](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html) which requires running reactor to work properly, see linked examples in docs. Your code sample will work just fine if you start Twisted reactor.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tst = Test()
    rtn = tst.deferredChain()
    reactor.run()
    print "RTN: %s " % rtn
```

[Twisted Treq](https://github.com/twisted/treq) is an interesting framework built on top of agents, it promises to give you python-requests like API for Twisted async HTTP client.

Comment: Thanks @Pawel for your answer. But this approach doesn't works yet. Maybe my question isn't clear. I did some adjust now. The need is, from a function inside a callback chain, to do a get request and check the http return code. Depending of this code, I want to make a specific return from original callback chain. My dificult is that the callback function of the get request isn't called.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling tst.deferredChain() synchronously and trying to read   d.result within it and this is not correct. The correct solution is letting it return a deferred as well and attach to it a callback.

Comment: Hi @pinturic! Thanks for your answer. If I understood well, I need to replace the synchronous call of my function deferredChain() by adding it as a callback of another deferred object. I tried to do this with the following code:
    `defA = defer.Deferred()`
    `defA.addCallback(Test.deferredChain)`
    `defA.callback("success")`
    `rtn = defA.result`
The new behavior seems to be a loop, whitout no response at the console. I don't know what is really happening now. Is this the correct solution to my problem? What I forgot?